# How to `rm dir/*/foo.txt` in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a directory with several subdirectories inside and several files inside those. I want to delete all files with the name 'foo.txt' in those subdirectories.

So basically I want Linux's `rm dir/*/foo.txt`, but `del dir\*\foo.txt` doesn't do it.

Also, the subdirectories might contain space characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work after moving to the top folder:

del /s foo.txt

Enter del /? to see the rest of the options.